# Custom Function Not Appearing in Google Sheets Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a set of custom functions for a specific spreadsheet, and there are a few new ones I tried making to alleviate a certain problem (it is specifically a spreadsheet of damage-per-second values).

I have merely fair knowledge of javascript, but provided below are the three functions I wrote into appscript:

```
/**
 * Find the total damage in a combo for a given super duration
 * 
 * @param {array} actionTimeArray indexed time values in combo
 * @param {array} actionDrainArray indexed drain values in combo
 * @param {number} superDuration base duration of super 
 * @returns {number} total time of a combo for a given super duration
 * @customfunction
 */
function combo_totalTime(actionTimeArray, actionDrainArray, superDuration) {
  // error check
  if (!Array.isArray(actionTimeArray)) throw new Error("actionTimeArray must be an array");
  else if (!Array.isArray(actionDrainArray)) throw new Error("actionDrainArray must be an array");
  else if (!(actionTimeArray.length == actionDrainArray.length)) throw new Error("All arrays must be of the same length");

  // calculate
  let index = 0;
  let totalTime = 0;
  while (superDuration >= 0) {
    totalTime += actionTimeArray[index];
    superDuration -= actionTimeArray[index] + (superDuration * actionDrainArray[index]);
    index = (index + 1) % actionTimeArray.length;
  }

  return totalTime;
}

/**
 * Find the total time for a combo for a given super duration
 * 
 * @param {array} damageArray indexed damage values in combo
 * @param {array} actionTimeArray indexed time values in combo
 * @param {array} actionDrainArray indexed drain values in combo
 * @param {number} superDuration base duration of super 
 * @return {number} total damage of combo for a given super duration
 * @customfunction
 */
function combo_totalDamage(damageArray, actionTimeArray, actionDrainArray, superDuration) {
  // error check
  if (!Array.isArray(damageArray)) throw new Error("damageArray must be an array");
  else if (!Array.isArray(actionTimeArray)) throw new Error("actionTimeArray must be an array");
  else if (!Array.isArray(actionDrainArray)) throw new Error("actionDrainArray must be an array");
  else if (!(damageArray.length == actionTimeArray.length == actionDrainArray.length)) throw new Error("All arrays must be of the same length");

  // calculate
  let index = 0;
  let totalDamage = 0;
  while (superDuration >= 0) {
    totalDamage += damageArray[index];
    superDuration -= actionTimeArray[index] + (superDuration * actionDrainArray[index]);
    index = (index + 1) % damageArray.length;
  }

  return totalDamage;
}

/**
 * Find the total DPS for a combo for a given super duration
 * 
 * @param {array} damageArray indexed damage values in combo
 * @param {array} actionTimeArray indexed time values in combo
 * @param {array} actionDrainArray indexed drain values in combo
 * @param {number} superDuration base duration of super 
 * @return {number} DPS of the combo for a given super duration
 * @customfunction
 */
function combo_totalDPS(damageArray, actionTimeArray, actionDrainArray, superDuration) {
  return combo_totalDamage(damageArray, actionTimeArray, actionDrainArray, superDuration) 
          / combo_totalTime(actionTimeArray, actionDrainArray, superDuration);
}
```

The intent is to pass same-length arrays and parse through them with the functions, and throw an error if the provided parameter isn't an array.

I expected the functions to just be visible in the spreadsheet, but they aren't.

Whenever I hit "Run" it throws an error, which I suppose is the reason why my functions aren't appearing. The error in question reads:

```
Error: actionTimeArray must be an array
combo_totalTime @ Code.gs:161
```

This is a custom-defined error.

As far as I know, there isn't a way to type variables in javascript, therefore making the parameters ambiguous. Why would it check a parameter, even if the function isn't used? Shouldn't it only throw an error if I use the function, not before I use it? What am I missing here that's causing it to throw this error and ultimately prevent me from using these functions?

Comment: `I expected the functions to just be visible in the spreadsheet, but they aren't.` I've just loaded your functions, and they definitely appear in the spreadsheet. I'm not passing judgement on whether they "work", but they are accessible. make sure that you have saved them; OTOH, they do NOT work but clicking "run". There's documentation on [how to use a custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_a_custom_function) - have you read that?

Comment: It seems like I might of just needed to refresh the page?

They're in my spreadsheet now after opening the spreadsheet up again today, so I guess the spreadsheet page just didn't load them in yet after saving the script.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all I needed to do was refresh the page for the functions to be recognized in my spreadsheet. I opened up the spreadsheet again today and they're in there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).